# Liquid Tite Flexible Conduit Into Breaker Panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am adding two circuits to an existing circuit panel in my home. One will be for a welder and will be on a 50a 2 pole breaker and terminate in a NEMA 6-50 outlet. It will be 3 6AWG THHN wires in 1" SCH40 PVC conduit.

The other circuit is for a 5hp Air Compressor and will be a 30a 2 pole breaker, 3 10AWG THHN that goes to a safety switch mounted on the wall and then finally to the air compressor pressure switch. This will be in 3/4" SCH40 PVC conduit.

I will have Liquid Tite going from the Safety Switch to the Air Compressor, but I am wondering if I can use it going from a junction box to the breaker panel too and be code compliant. The conduit I am running will be surface mounted on drywall as the room the panel is in has drywall on the panel wall side. I will cut a small access hole under the panel and this is where I am hoping to use liquid tite to go up and into the breaker panel to avoid having to plumb a short bent section up into the panel from a surface mounted pull box or the like.

Would this be code compliant? Any other holes in my plan? I know the conduit is oversized, but I am doing this on purpose for sake of easy pulls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Liquidtite to go into a main panel. I've got to ask why you're using it and not flexible metal conduit. FMC is more readily available and provides much better protection. The last time I checked, I think it was cheaper.

Comment: FMC also pulls much easier. LFNC is the most miserable thing to pull wires through I've ever personally experienced.

Comment: This is a very good point and one I hadn't thought of. Thanks much for the info!